# Find the inverse function of $y=x|x|e^x$

Tags: inverse

I am having problems finding the inverse function of a complicated function. 
In this case: $$y=x|x|e^x $$

I thought I could 'split' this function but I'm not sure if that's the right way.
for $y=x$ it would be $x=y$
for $y=e^x$ it would be $x=\ln(y)$
for $y=|x|$ we need to split it in 2 cases: if $x<0, y=-x,$ if $x>0, y=x $

So all together it would be:
for $x<0$:
$$y = x \cdot (-x) \cdot \ln y $$
$$-x^2= y/\ln y$$
$$x = - \sqrt{\frac{y}{\ln y}} $$

For $x>0$:
$$y = x \cdot x \cdot ln y $$ 
$$x^2 = y/\ln y  $$
$$x = \sqrt{\frac{y}{\ln y}}  $$

Is this the right way of solving this case? I would be grateful for any help

Comment: For some reason the 'enters' didn't work out. So I meant the result would be 1. (for x<0) x = - sqrt(y/lny), and for the other case 2. (for x>0) it would be x = sqrt (y/lny)

Comment: You need the Lambert W function

Comment: But we never used Lambert W function, I've never heard of it. Is my way of solving it wrong?

Comment: You can check if your solution is right by checking if $(x(y(x))=1$ (I doubt it). The splitting approach is good.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambert W function is defined as the inverse of $f(x) = xe^x$.

If $y=x^2e^x$, then $$\frac 12\sqrt y = \frac x2e^{\frac{x}{2}}$$ so that $x =2 W(\frac12 \sqrt y)$. Changing variables, our inverse is

$$f^{-1}(x) = 2 W(\frac12 \sqrt x)$$

Of course, the above only solves your problem for $x \geq 0$. I'm sure you can modify it for $x<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helpful but I'm afraid the Lambert W function wasn't mentioned so I hoped there would be other way of solving it. Thank you anyway